# Reading input and writing output of a linked list from a file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am dealing with a mixed type of numbers and strings so i really have no idea how to do this except for something so simple like

```
ifstream fin(filename);
fin >> a;
ofstream fout(filename);
fout << b;
```

and here is the struct i have to deal with

```
struct Reservation
{
    int ID;
    char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
    char phone[MAX_PHONE_LENGTH];
    int gridironID;
    char hireDate[MAX_DATE_LENGTH];
    char resDate[MAX_DATE_LENGTH];
    char startTime[MAX_TIME_LENGTH];
    char endTime[MAX_TIME_LENGTH];
    bool isPay;

    Reservation *nextReservation;
};
```

I really need some guidances or directions to start it , maybe with a specific kind of function or operator that i should use ?

Edit : ah yes i want the output to look like this

```
100001,khang,01283478233,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

The whole idea is to read the informations on a file from the start when you run the program , which in order to create a base resources for interacting with , after everything is done , you want to print out the informations in the base resources for the next time you start the program again.

Comment: Do you only need to output the values? Because you only gave an example for your desired output

Comment: the whole idea is to read the informations on a file from the start when you run the program , which in order to create a base resources for interacting with , after everything is done , you want to print out the informations in the base resources for the next time you start the program again.

Comment: I get that, but how does that input file look like?

Comment: actually the input and the output is from the same file . the input session is to read what in it , the output session is to overwrite the old informations with the new informations which you have interating with(for example deleting some informations or adding new ones) :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For output, simply use the `ostream` interface (which works with `cin` or `fstream` or...)

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Reservation& reservation) {
    stream 
           << reservation.ID << "," 
           << reservation.name << "," 
           //... and so on
}
```

For parsing the input, if you can assume that the fields will always be separated by a single `','` (no spaces), and your strings (like name) *won't contain commas or spaces*, you can do:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, Reservation& reservation) {
    stream >> reservation.ID;
    stream::char_type ignored;
    stream >> ignored; // skip over ','

    std::string aString;
    stream >> aString; // read name
    // Now copy to char array. To make sure we don't overflow it,
    // cut string to MAX_NAME_SIZE, and leave additional space for the
    // terminating '\0'.
    aString = aString.substr(0, MAX_NAME_SIZE-1);
    strcpy(reservation.name, aString.c_str());

    // and so on..
}
```

But this is a very basic solution. It will suffice if your input format is guaranteed to fulfill my assumptions noted above, and if you absolutely don't want to use 3rd party code. But in general, I'd advise you to find a library to read & write CSV data, or similar. It makes handling details like quoted strings, additional whitespace etc. much simpler.

And you still need to create the link relationships between your `Reservation`s.

Comment: i suppose i would add something like this will make it a linked list ?   :   Reservation* res;
    res->nextReservation = reservationHeader;
    reservationHeader = res;

Comment: In general you create a linked list by setting `nextReservation` to the next record's address, yes. You'll also need to heap allocate each record. But if you're not sure how to create a linked list, that's a different question. You should already find a lot of material here on SO and elsewhere. Feel free to ask a new question if you run into problems.

Comment: I don't think your input will work if there is a space in the name.  There are two ways around this: when reading the name, use `std::getline( stream, name, ',' )`, or temporarily imbue the stream with a locale whose `codecvt` treats `','`, and only `','` as white space, and then use `>>`.  (Both sort of seem like a bit of abuse to me---especially the solution with imbue.)

Comment: Also (no doubt because this is a C++ forum, and you were thinking purely of the C++ aspects), you forgot the most important part.  Before writing either of the two operators, he should define exactly what he wants the format to be.

Comment: @JamesKanze good point. I assumed he would only have strings without spaces, but totally forgot to mention that. I'll add it. Regarding the format: I was going by what he edited into his question, but yes, he hasn't clearly defined it yet..

Comment: The problem is that he doesn't say.  I proposed an extremely radical solution (quoting the strings) which is likely overkill; it's probable that he can find a separator which cannot occur in his strings; some variant of your solution could be simpler in such a case.  (If human readability isn't an issue, I'd probably choose `'|'` instead of `','`, but that's not the issue.)

Comment: By the way: `strncpy` is _not_ a good idea, since it can leave the string without a `'\0'` terminator.  I'd resize `aString` if it were too big, and use `strcpy`.  Or set an error if the string is too long; given his use case, it should never happen.

Comment: @JamesKanze again, good catch. I changed the code to truncate `aString`.

Answer (score 1):

Without some information regarding the actual data in the
strings, it's hard to say, but basically, you'll need to define
the functions:

```
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& dest, Reservation const& source )
std::istream& operator>>( std::ostream& source, Reservation& dest );
```

What you put in the functions depends a bit on the data you have
to deal with; your first step should be to define exactly what
you want each record to look like, keeping in mind that it must
be unambiguous on input.  (For example, if you just use white
space as a separator, you'll run into problems if any of the
strings can contain white space—and names typically can.)

Outputting the targetted format is relatively simple: you output
each field, with the necessary separators, etc., in the
classical way.  Input is more complicated, because you need to
verify that the desired separators are actually present; if
worst comes to worst, you may even have to read character by
character, e.g. if you want to use quoted strings for the name:

```
std::string name;       //  Where we'll put the results;
source >> std::skipws;  //  Skip any leading white space
char ch;
if ( !source.get() || ch != '"' ) {
    source.setstate( std::ios_base::failbit );
}
while ( source.get( ch ) && ch != '"' ) {
    name += ch;
}
if ( ch != '"' ) {
    source.setstate( std::ios_base::failbit );
}
```

You may want to add code to handle escaped characters in the
loop, or ban other characters, like `'\n'` in the input.  This
is fairly easy to do in the loop.  Just remember that anytime
you see anything you don't like: set `std::ios_base::failbit`.
In addition to telling the caller that something went wrong, all
of the following input will fail immediately, without extracting
anything from the stream.

Comment: thank you sir , definitely use it to assist my works to its fullness potential.